# jasmine test $scope is undefinded

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I try to write a controller test using karma with jasmine.
I get this error "Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown SettingsProvider <- settings"
I been stuck for hours googling around but I can't found a solution for this.

My test Case

```
describe('MyController', function() {


     var $scope, controller;

     beforeEach(module('MyApp'));
     beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
         $scope = $rootScope.$new();
         controller = $controller('MyController', { 
            $scope: $scope
         });

     }));
     it('sets the options to "valid" if the type is  val', function() {
          var type = 'val';
          $scope.callOptions(type);
          expect($scope.options).toBeTruthy();
    });

});
```

My karma.config.js

```
 files: [
      'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'app/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',  
      'app/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js', 
      'app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',  
      'app/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js',
      'app/metronic/assets/global/plugins/angularjs/plugins/angular-ui-router.min.js',
      'app/bower_components/ui-router-extras/release/modular/ct-ui-router-extras.sticky.js',
      'app/bower_components/ngDraggable/ngDraggable.js',
      'app/metronic/assets/global/plugins/angularjs/angular-sanitize.min.js',
      'app/metronic/assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js',
      'app/metronic/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js',
      'app/metronic/assets/global/plugins/angularjs/plugins/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js',


      'app/bower_components/ngstorage/ngStorage.min.js',
      'app/bower_components/oclazyload/dist/ocLazyLoad.min.js',

      'app/metronic/assets/global/plugins/angularjs/plugins/angular-file-upload/angular-file-upload.min.js',

      'app/js/services/myProvider.js',
      'app/js/app.js',      
      'app/controllers/MyController.js'
   ]
```

My controller :

```
MetronicApp.controller('MyController',
        ['$http',
            '$rootScope',
            '$scope',
            '$window',
            function ($http, $rootScope, $scope, $window) {

              $scope.callOptions = function (type) {
                    if (type == 'val') {
                        return $scope.optionsVal;
                    }
                    ;
                    if (type == 'Num') {
                        return $scope.optionsNum;
                    }
                    ;

                };
              });
```

**EDIT**

I delete some file from my karma.config.js and now I get this error $scope is undefined ..This is a screen shot of the error :
[image]

Comment: Your controller probably depends on a service named "settings", that is not available because you forgot to load its module or because its JS file is not listed. Post the code of the controller. Another suspect thing is that you don't have any test file in the list of files of the karma config.

Comment: Thank you @JB Nizet for your unswer I have just edited my question and add my controller .. But I don't have any service which named "settings" in my project and the only module on which depends my controller is "myProvider" and it's already add in the karma.config.js.

Comment: I'd start by cleaning all those dependencies. You're importing ui-router 3 times, sanitize 2 times, angular-routedespit I guess you're using ui-router, bootstrap although you're using ui-bootstrap, jquery two times. It's a mess. Just include what you really, really need.

Comment: I just add a screen shot to my quetion @JB Nizet and I have deleted all duplicated file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way you injected $rootScope and $controller is incorrect.Please try following code snippet.It will do the thing.

```
  describe('MyController', function() {


 var $scope, controller;

 beforeEach(module('MyApp'));
 beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
     $scope = $injector.get("$rootScope").$new();
     controller = $injector.get("$controller")('MyController', { 
        $scope: $scope
     });

 }));
 it('sets the options to "valid" if the type is  val', function() {
      var type = 'val';
      $scope.callOptions(type);
      expect($scope.options).toBeTruthy();
});
```

});